# Recursion in c++ in the example of merge sort

Tags: c++

I have a very general question about recursion in c++. For a better understanding I use the following example of merge sort to explain my unsureness.

```
   void mergesort (int* first, int* last)
{
   int n = last - first;
   if (n<=1)return;
   int* middle = first + n/2;
   mergesort (first, middle);
   mergesort (middle, last);
   merge (first,middle, last);
}
```

where the function `merge`has to be defined. The function arguments `int* first,int* last`are to pointers pointing to the first and last element in an array respectively. Let say the array has length 10. Let's see what happens:

1. Since 10 is greater then 1, we declare a pointer `int* middle = first + 5;`.

Now my question: We are calling `mergesort(first, middle)`, and this recursion will end as soon as we have split the first have of the array in single "elements". But is `mergesort(middle,last)` execute after `mergesort(first,middle)` has terminated or at the same time? Somehow it must be at the same time, otherwise we do not split up the second half into single "elements". Same question with merge sort in the last time. So how does recursion execute several function calls?

**EDIT** I've added the complete source code as well as an output:

```
//Mergesort.cpp
//

#include <iostream>
void merge (int* first, int* middle, int* last)
{
  int n = last - first;
  std::cout<<"merge part, n= " << n<<"\n";
  std::cout<<"merge part, middle= " << *middle << "\n";
  std::cout<<"merge part, last= "<<*last << "\n";
  int* deck = new int[n];

  int* left = first;
  std::cout<<"merge part, left = first " << *left<< "\n";
  int* right = middle;
  std::cout << "merge part, right = middle " << *right << "\n";
  for (int* d = deck; d!=deck+n;++d){
    if (left == middle) *d = *right++;
    else if (right==last ) *d=*left++;
    else if (*left < *right) *d = *left++;
    else *d = *right++;}

  int *d = deck;
  while (first != middle) *first++ = *d++;
  while (middle != last) *middle++ = *d++;

  delete[] deck;
}


void mergesort (int* first, int* last)
{
  int n = last - first;
  if (n <= 1) return;
  std::cout << "n= " << n;
  int* middle = first + n/2;
  std::cout << "first = "<< *first << "middle = "<< *middle<<"\n";
  mergesort (first, middle);
  mergesort (middle, last);
  merge (first, middle, last);
}

int main () 
{
  int a[4]={6,2,1,3};
  int* first = a;
  int* last = a+4;
  mergesort (first, last);
  std::cout<< a[0]<< a[1]<< a[2]<< a[3]<<"\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ThinkStation-S20:~/c++/test_files$ ./mergesort 
n= 4first = 6middle = 1
n= 2first = 6middle = 2
merge part, n= 2
merge part, middle= 2
merge part, last= 1
merge part, left = first 6
merge part, right = middle 2
n= 2first = 1middle = 3
merge part, n= 2
merge part, middle= 3
merge part, last= 4197792
merge part, left = first 1
merge part, right = middle 3
merge part, n= 4
merge part, middle= 1
merge part, last= 4197792
merge part, left = first 2
merge part, right = middle 1
1236
```

Comment: Try adding `printf` or `cout` statements in your code before each line to understand the order things execute in.  Although it might be confusing at first, the effort you take to understand what you see will really help you understand recursion.

Answer (score 2):

C++, like C, executes statements in order, one after another. So the second call to mergesort will occur after the first one returns. With an appropriate definition of `merge`, that will work just fine. I strongly suggest that you try the program yourself, simulating the computer with paper and pencil. It won't take you too long (honest!) and it should resolve your doubts.

Like quicksort, mergesort can be (partially) executed in parallel. The two recursive calls to mergesort are independent of each other so there execution could overlap. But C++ won't do that for you without quite a bit of extra work.

---

Here's one way to do this with pencil and paper, which I think is easier to understand than trying to interpret printf output.

1. Make about a dozen card-size papers.
2. Start with the first call to mergesort, from `main`.
3. Grab one of the cards, and fill in the four variables: first, last, middle, n.
4. Step through the lines of mergesort until you reach a new call. Write the line number of the call on the current card, put it on the "stack" (which starts off empty), and continue with step 3.
5. When you reach the end of mergesort, discard the current card and go back to the previous one, which will be on the top of the stack. Continue with step 4, starting with the next line in mergesort.
6. When you've done all the cards you started with, you're done.

Comment: thanks for you answer. I tried to simulate it with pencil and paper. Some questions: Calling `mergesort(first,middle)` return nothing (void) as soon as the middle pointer points to the second element. Then `mergesort(middle,last)` is called. Which middle is there used?

Comment: @math: every time you enter `mergesort` you create a new context ("stack frame") with its own parameters and local variables. So when you do the exercise on paper, each mergesort has its own first, middle, last and n. Also, each mergesort returns to the mergesort which called it.

Comment: Yes, I agree. for example, my array is {6,4,1,3}. `first` points to 6 and `last` to 3. Then n = 4, my first `middle`, called `middle1` points to 1. Then recursion is applied to `mergesort(first,middle1)`, n=2 and my new middle pointer, `middle2`points to 4. In the next recursion we get a return. What does happen now?

Comment: control returns to the caller which calls mergesort(middle,last), using its middle and last.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I've added the complete sourcecode as well as an output. It does not call mergesort (middle,last) after ending with the first part. The next output is from `merge`. I don't understand why the first `last` points to 1, neither.

Comment: @math: (1) You can't see all the calls to mergesort because the printf in mergesort is after the `if`. (2) You really need to insert some spaces; that output is unreadable. (3) Outputting *last is incorrect, since last might point outside of the array. In general, it's easier to see what's going on if you print the offset into the array. It would also help for you to print the recursion depth.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens at the same time, it helps to think of each successive function call as adding to a stack.  At the end of the function it pops of the stack and continues.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_r0gV2hQYf0